# Array values not append in list

Tags: ios, arrays, swift4

```
class Model1:NSObject {

    var name1:String = ""
    var size1:String = ""
    var colour1:String = ""

init (name:String, size:String, colour:String) {
    self.name1 = name
    self.size1 = size
    self.colour1 = colour
  }
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

        var list2 = [Model1]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            var array1 = ["1","2","3","4"]
            var array2 = ["one","two","three","four"]
            var array3 = ["one111","two222","three333","four444"]
            // var list11 = [array1[0], array2[0], array3[0]]

            let elm11 = Model1(name: array1[0], size: array2[0], colour: array3[0])  //Error
            list2.append(elm11)

            print("result)\(Model1(name: array1[0], size: array2[0], colour: array3[0]))") ////Error (result<searchTableview.Model1: 0x604000288610>)

            list2.append(Model1(name: array1[0], size: array2[0], colour: array3[0]))
            print("list2.append(Model1(name: array1[0], size: array1[0], colour: array1[0]))\(list2.append(Model1(name: array1[0], size: array1[0], colour: array1[0])))")
        }
    }
```

Above code Array values not append in list. if i am using my code i
am getting the error of
               searchTableview.Model1: 0x604000288610

I want to result is

```
   Model1(name: "1", size: "one", colour: "one111")
   Model1(name: "2", size: "two", colour: "two222")
   Model1(name: "3", size: "three", colour: "three333")
```

how can i getting my output please help me!

Comment: Above code is working for me. i have tested in playground.

Comment: Thanks for your response.list 2 does not append in list values

Comment: print("result)\(Model1(name: array1[0], size: array2[0], colour: array3[0]))") This line output is  result<searchTableview.Model1: 0x6000002893d0>

Comment: you just want to print like this `Model1(name: "1", size: "one", colour: "one111")` or want to use array of `Model1 `?

Comment: Model1(name: "1", size: "one", colour: "one111") i want to this format from mutiple arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your array of your class with below code:

```
class Model1:NSObject {

    var name1:String = ""
    var size1:String = ""
    var colour1:String = ""

init (name:String, size:String, colour:String) {
    self.name1 = name
    self.size1 = size
    self.colour1 = colour
  }
}

var arrItems = [Model1]()

arrItems.append(Model1(name: "Test 1", size: "1", colour: "Black"))
arrItems.append(Model1(name: "Test 2", size: "2", colour: "Blue"))

print("Name is \(arrItems[0].name1)")
```

> Output:
>
> Name is Test 1